# No module named 'adbase' - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

> EDIT: There's already a question like this satisfied.
>
> [pyad: Installs fine, but says it can't find adbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40004147/pyad-installs-fine-but-says-it-cant-find-adbase)
>
> Thank's to birryree to show me the way.
> Sorry for the duplicate

When I `import pyad` library to my code, i get the following answer:

```
>>> import pyad
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\cfplaster\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyad\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from adbase import set_defaults as pyad_setdefaults
ImportError: No module named 'adbase'
```

As you can see, Python is installed on my user like everything else related to Python.

Some information:

> Windows 10 x64;
>
> Python 3.5;
>
> Pywin32 already installed;
>
> Environment variable PATH is already with *python* and *pip* directory;

Ask for some more information if you want.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Looks like a bug on the current release of `pyad`. Perhaps this thread answers your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40004147/pyad-installs-fine-but-says-it-cant-find-adbase

Comment: Thank you, i didn't saw that... i even search for duplicates but found nothing. Thanks again